# evaluate $\oint_C \frac{1}{z-i} dz$ where C is the circle $\left\vert 2 \right\vert$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I've tried several times to solve this integral, but I am unable to solve it, every time I get a similar wrong answer. The question is "evaluate $$\oint_C \frac{1}{z-i} dz$$ where C is the circle $\left\vert 2 \right\vert$"

Here is my (wrong) solution:

This function is not analytic in $z=i$. This point is part of the circle $\left\vert 2 \right\vert$, so the cauchy's integral theorem does not hold here.

The parametric equation for the curve is:

$$
z(t)=2e^{it}
$$
where $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$
and
$$
\frac {dz}{dt} = 2ie^{it}
$$

and also:
$$
f(z(t))=\frac {1}{z(t)-i}=\frac {1}{2e^{it}-i}
$$

So:
$$
\oint_C f(z(t))\cdot z'(t)dt = \oint\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2ie^{it}}{2e^{it}-i}dt
$$

I used $u=2e^{it}-i$ and $du=2ie^{it}dt$ to solve the integral.

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac {du}{u}=Ln(u)=Ln(2e^{it}-i)
$$

Now if I substitute $2\pi$ and $0$:
$$
Ln(2e^{i(2\pi)}-i) - Ln(2e^{i(0)}-i) = Ln(2-i)-Ln(2-i)=0
$$

But the book says the answer is "$2\pi i$". What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: @marwalix That isn't quite the issue, OP goes back to presubstitute.

Comment: After working this problem you might look up 'calculus of residues' to see how to do this sort of problem in general.

Comment: the parameterisation is wrong no? the circle of radius 2 centred at $i$ is $|z-i| = 2$ therefore $z(t)-i = 2e^{it}$

Comment: @IsmailBello The circle is $|z|=2$

Comment: The problem is that $\frac{1}{u}$ has no global primitive on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. You can use Cauchy's integral theorem to find the integral is the same as $$\int_{\lvert z-i\rvert = \frac{1}{2}} \frac{dz}{z-i}.$$ You can directly evaluate that using a parametrisation. Or you can define $$F(w) = \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 2} \frac{dz}{z-w},$$ note $F(0) = 2\pi i$, and differentiate to see $F' \equiv 0$.

Comment: @avid19 sorry I thought he said the circle was centered at $i$, my mistake

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula perhpas?

Comment: @mrf, No, that's the topic of the next section in my book (a translation of Advanced Engineering Mathematics, 7th edition, by Erwin Kreyszig). I didn't read that section, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the function $1/u$ does not have a primitive defined on all of $C$.  The complex logarithm is typically defined with branch cuts, since 
$$ e^{2\pi i} = e^{0} ~~ {\rm but } ~~ 2\pi i \neq 0, $$
leading to an ambiguity in the definition of $\log$ at $z=1$ (for example!).
To deal with this in the most elementary way, you can separate the integral into real and imaginary parts and attempt to integrate each separately.  This process looks like a huge bummer, so instead you can expand the function $f(z)$ into its Laurent series about $z = i$ and apply the residue theorem.

Probably more helpful: you could draw a second circle of unit radius about $z = i$, call it $C_2$.  Then by Cauchy's theorem, 
$$ \int_C f(z) dz = \int_{C-C_2} f(z) dz + \int_{C_2} f(z) dz = \int_{C_2} f(z)dz.$$
That is, traversing $C$ once can be broken up into (i) traversing $C$ starting from $z = 2i$, counterclockwise; (ii) traversing $C_2$ starting at the same point, *clockwise* (these two steps give a path I labelled $C - C_2$); (iii) traversing $C_2$ again, counterclockwise.

The two trips along $C_2$ cancel out, but by grouping the first two legs of the journey we get a contour which *doesn't contain the singularity* $z = i$.  Cauchy's theorem then implies that the line integral along $C - C_2$ is zero.

Now to evaluate $\int_{C_2} f(z) dz$, we can translate the problem to integrating $1/z$ about the unit circle, $C_0$ (substitute $w = z-i$).  This leaves

$$\int_C {1 \over z - i} dz = \int_{C_2} {1\over z - i} dz = \int_{C_0} {dw \over w} = \int_0^{2\pi} {ie^{it} \over e^{it}} dt = i\int_0^{2\pi} dt = 2\pi i.$$

Daniel Fischer's comment is an excellent suggestion.  I prefer his solution, but this is what I've got :)

Answer (score 1):

As shown below, you cannot integrate $\frac1z$ around the singularity at the origin and get a value that matches the value you started with. This means that $\log(z)$ cannot be well-defined in a neighborhood of the origin.

---

The following computation might simply be a translated version of Titus's answer.  If so, perhaps the translation and diagram add some value.

Substituting $z\mapsto z+i$, we get
$$
\int_{\left|z\right|=2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-i}
=\int_{\left|z+i\right|=2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\tag{1}
$$
Since the contour below does not circle the origin,

[image]

[Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) says that
$$
\int_{\left|z+i\right|=2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}
-\int_{\left|z\right|=1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\tag{2}
=0
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\left|z+i\right|=2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}
&=\int_{\left|z\right|=1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\\[3pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2\pi i}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can hit this with Cauchy's Integral formula:

\begin{align}
\int_{\vert z \vert = 2}\frac{1}{z-i}dz&=2\pi i \bigg((1)\bigg\vert_{z=i} \bigg)\\
&=2\pi i (1)\\
&=2\pi i.
\end{align}

Which was the desired result, and we are done. This is my favorite method if it can be applied. So I call the function $f(z)=1$ here the }rest of the function, function" because when computing, you take "the rest of the function" aside from the portion with the singularity, and plug in the singularity into the rest and take an $n$th derivative when necessary, in this case $n=0$ so we need not take any derivatives, so if your denominator was squared, the result would be zero.