# Evaluating an integral over a closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-2} $ where $\gamma $ is the circle $|z|=3$.

Try:

We know $\gamma(t) = 3e^{it}$ where $t \in [0,2 \pi] $. So,

$$\int \frac{ dz}{z-2} = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ 3 i e^{it} \, dt}{3e^{it}{-2}}$$

When I solve this integral I get $0$. But, according to my notes, I should get $2 \pi i $. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This is closely related to [evaluate $\oint_C \frac{1}{z-i} dz$ where C is the circle $\left\vert 2 \right\vert$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1446224). My answer to that question should answer this question with the proper rotation and scaling :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem), the integral over the following contour is $0$:

[image: difference of contours]

This contour is the difference of the contour for $\left|\,z\,\right|=3$ and the contour $\left|\,z-2\,\right|=1$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=3}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2}
&=\int_{|z-2|=1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2}\\
&=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i\,e^{it}\,\mathrm{d}t}{e^{it}}\\[6pt]
&=2\pi i
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hard to guess how you "solved" the integral, but due to the residue theorem,

$$ \int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z-2} = 2\pi i\cdot \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z-2},z=2\right) = 2\pi i.$$

You may check that the integral along $\gamma$ is the same along $|z-2|=1$, counter-clockwise oriented.

Comment: (+1) I could rotate and relabel the circles in the diagram from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1446337/13854) and it would illustrate your answer :-)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'll neutralize.  But I suspect the down vote was a consequence of the fact that the OP stated prior knowledge of the value of the integral and seemed to be asking how to recover the result directly evaluating the parametrically described integral.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @JackD'Aurizio, the integral can be evaluated quickly using the residue theorem.

If one is interested, however, in evaluating the integral more directly, then we can proceed as in the OP.  We describe the contour $\gamma$ parametrically as $z=3e^{it}$.  Then, the integral of interest is

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ 3 i e^{it} }{3e^{it}-2}\,dt&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ 3 i e^{it}\left(3e^{-it}-2\right) }{13-12\cos t}\,dt \tag 1\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ 3 i \left(3-2\cos t\right) }{13-12\cos t}\,dt \tag 2\\\\
&=\frac i2\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ 18-12\cos t }{13-12\cos t}\,dt \tag 3\\\\
&=i\pi+\frac i2\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ 5 }{13-12\cos t}\,dt \tag 4\\\\
&=i\pi+\frac i2\,5\frac{ 2\pi }{5} \tag 5\\\\
&=i2\pi
\end{align}$$

as expected!

---

**NOTE 1:**

In arriving at the right-hand side of $(1)$, we used $\frac{ 3 i e^{it} }{3e^{it}-2}=\frac{ 3 i e^{it} }{3e^{it}-2}\frac{3e^{-it}-2}{3e^{-it}-2}=\frac{ 3 i e^{it}\left(3e^{-it}-2\right) }{13-12\cos t}$.

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we exploited the facts that (i) the sine function is odd, periodic function with period $2\pi$, and (ii) the integral of an odd function about symmetric limits is zero.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we simply multiplied and divided by $6$ and brought the factor $i/2$ outside the integral.

In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we split the numerator into $5+(13-12\cos t$, and simplified by carrying out the integral of $1$.

In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, used the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) $\tan(t/2)=x$ to carry our the integral.

---

**NOTE 2:**

It might be tempting to write naively

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ 3 i e^{it} }{3e^{it}-2}\,dt=\left.\log (3e^{it}-2)\right|_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}=\log (3-2)-\log (3-2)=0$$

This reason that this is not correct is that the complex logarithm is not a single-valued function in the complex plane. Instead, we have $\log (3e^{it}-2)=\log |3e^{it}-2|+i\arg(3e^{it}-2)$.

If we restrict the argument of $3e^{it}-2$ such that $0\le \arg(3e^{it}-2) <2\pi$, then for $t=0$, $\arg(3e^{it}-2)=0$, while at $t=2\pi^{-}$, $\arg(3e^{it}-2)=2\pi$ and the integral of interest is $i2\pi$.